# How can I find the memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm building a function that reads a text file and returns one line each time the function is called. The output seems to be correct. However, I keep getting a memory leak which I can't seem to fix it no matter what I do.

I have the following code.

```
BUFFERSIZE = 10;
char    *modify(char buffer[], char *line)
{
    const int   size = ft_strclen(line, '\n') + 1;
    const int   total = strlen(line) - size;
    int             i;
    char            *return_line;

    i = 0;
    return_line = malloc(sizeof(char) * ft_strclen(line, '\n') + 2);
    if (!return_line)
        return (NULL);
    while (i < size && line[i])
    {
        return_line[i] = line[i];
        i++;
    }
    return_line[i] = '\0';
    i = 0;
    while (i < total && line[size + i])
    {
        buffer[i] = line[size + i];
        i++;
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    free(line);
    return (return_line);
}



char    *join_buffers(char *buf1, char *buf2)
{
    const int   length = strlen(buf1) + strlen(buf2);
    char            *new;
    int             i = 0;
    int             k = 0;
    
    new = NULL;
    new = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    if (!new)
        return (NULL);
    while (i < length && buf1[i])
    {
        new[i] = buf1[i];
        i++;
    }
    new[length] = '\0';
    while(i < length && buf2[k])
        new[i++] = buf2[k++]; // Not sure about this
    new[i] = '\0';
    return (new);
}

char    *read_file(char *buffer, int fd)
{
    int         bytes_read;
    char        buff_read[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    
    bytes_read = -1;
    while (!search_char(buffer, '\n'))
    {
        bytes_read = read(fd, buff_read, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (bytes_read == -1)
            return (NULL);
        if (bytes_read == 0)
            break ;
        buff_read[bytes_read] = '\0';
        buffer = join_buffers(buffer, buff_read);
    }
    return (buffer);
}


char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    char                *line;

    line = NULL;
    if (fd < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || read(fd, 0, 0) < 0)
        return (NULL);
    buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';
    line = read_file(buffer, fd);
    if (line[0] == '\0' && buffer[0] == '\0')
        return (NULL);
    line = modify(buffer, line);
    return (line);
}
```

I was thinking that I have to free line in the modify function. That fixes some leaks but not all of them.

Leaks without free in modify():
9 (256 bytes)
[...]

Leaks with free:
5 (128 bytes)
[...]

I've hidden the pointer addresses.

**What am I forgetting to free or is the problem elsewhere?**
Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: I found that the remaining leaks come from not freeing new join buffers. I do not understand when I have to free them though.

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
line = NULL;
free(line);
```

changes what `line` was originally pointing to, such that it now points to `NULL`. You have now lost access to the original memory and have no way to `free` it in this function, and as you didn't `free` the memory in the calling function, it resulted in a leak.

Aside:

```
free (NULL);
```

performs no operation.

Comment: Yes, the caller too overwrote the original value, with another value returned by this function `modify`, which should not have set it to `NULL` before calling `free`.

Comment: Hay I actually don't have that in my last edit of my code, I forgot to remove it from the post